# Block link switching while animating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a small problem with my code and can't find a solution to it. In my page there is a top bar with links (Home, About, Sign-up), each link possesses it's own content. Say the user is currently viewing the 'Home' content and then he clicks on 'About', the page is supposed to hide the 'Home' content and then show the 'About' content.

However I noticed that there's a bug if you click on another link while there is a content animating, so I created a variable called `AllowLinkSwitch` to block the user from switching to another link if there's still an animation going on.

```
this.ContentHideThenShow = function(contentHide, contentShow, contentShowHeight) 
{
    this.AllowLinkSwitch = false;
    $(contentHide).animate({
        height: "0px"
    }, 300, function(){
        $(contentHide).hide();
        $(contentShow).show();
        $(contentShow).animate({
            height: contentShowHeight
        }, 300, function(){ this.AllowLinkSwitch = true; });
    });
}
```

First I set `AllowLinkSwitch` to `false` when the function is called and then set it to `true` when the animation ends, but the variable is never set back to `true` and I can't switch to other links, the above code only works if I put the `this.AllowLinkSwitch = true;` line outside of the animate function, but I don't want it to work like that because that bug still happens, I need that variable to be set to `true` once the animation ends, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `animate()` callback, `this` will not be the same reference to the outer object. You need to store the reference outside of that function. Try this:

```
this.ContentHideThenShow = function(contentHide, contentShow, contentShowHeight) {
    var _this = this; // store reference here
    _this.AllowLinkSwitch = false;
    $(contentHide).animate({
        height: "0px"
    }, 300, function() {
        $(contentHide).hide();
        $(contentShow).show().animate({
            height: contentShowHeight
        }, 300, function(){ 
            _this.AllowLinkSwitch = true;  // use here
        });
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the use of the animation state flag entirely by using `if (!$(contentShow).is(':animated'))` to check if the element is currently animating and prevent logic from occurring where needed in your code.

Comment: Thank you! It worked just great!!! That function actually belongs to a constructor as you might have noticed, so now I created a private "_this" to use it where I was having similar problems, thank you so much! I've been trying to find out what was wrong with it for hours...

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.AllowLinkSwitch` variable IS setted to `true`, but only in function scope, you should use global variable.